# Difference between "Por medio de" and "Mediante"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Could someone please explain me the intricacy of using 'por medio de' over 'mediante'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between *mediante* and *por medio de*; they are (to my knowledge) exact synonyms, and can be used one in place of the other everywhere, except in a few fixed phrases like

- *Por medio de la presente…* (used to begin a formal letter or communication)
- *Dios mediante* ("God willing", though in this case *mediante* is used in a very particular way, suggesting divine intercession or mediation)

The Dictionary of the Royal Academy even defines *[mediante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OkJXvGN)* with reference to *por medio de*.

Besides the meaning, there's also no difference in the usual placement of these two words, with the exception, again, of fixed phrases. Because *mediante* is technically a lexicalized present participle*, it can appear after its object, as in *Dios mediante*, but this is a extremely particular idiomatic usage.

---

*The verb *mediar* means "to mediate, to intercede".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I think i can mark the question as accepted. One more question i have though. Is there any significant difference in where in the sentence you use one or the other expression? It feels that one is mostly used at the beginning of the sentence, while other in the middle

Comment: No, no difference there either. I've just updated the answer to include that, so as not to leave it in a comment.